# American English: poor vs. pour

Tags: pronunciation

Is there any difference in the pronunciations of poor and pour in American English?

I can't hear a difference (in my own pronunciation), at all.

Consulting the advanced English dictionary I'm finding two different IPA spellings:

poor: p'ʊr

pour: p'ɔːr

But I'm imagining this is based off of British English, where there is a clear difference in pronunciation of both words.

Comment: Which American English? There are several dialects, each with its own pronunciation quirks.

Comment: As a British native-speaker from London I pronounce _poor_ and _pour_ (and _paw_ and _pore_) identically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which advanced English dictionary did you use?
The online version of the Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary (OALD):

[poor](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/poor)

> pɔː(r) (BrE) ; pɔːr (Ame)
>   pʊə(r) (BrE) ; pʊr  (AmE)

[pour](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pour)

> pɔː(r) (BrE) ; pɔːr  (AmE)

So it seems that in both BrE and AmE, the two *may* be pronounced the same way.

Comment: And I can also add that in Australian English, 'poor' and 'pore' and 'pour' are usually identical.